# Arduino fuction outside loop

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

im trying to use a func inside Loop in Arduino. It wont work;
Params are numeroPin, sonido and delay. I tried everything but it seems like im not able to fix this

```
void setup() {


 for(int i = 2 ; i<=9; i++){
   pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
 }


}


 int C4 = 262; // LED 4
 int D4 = 294; // LED 5
 int E4 = 330; // LED 6
 int F4 = 349; // LED 7
 int G4 = 392; // LED 8
 int C5 = 523; // LED 9


void sonar(numeroPin, sonido, delay) {
 tone(2, sonido);
 digitalWrite(numeroPin, HIGH);
 delay(delay);
 digitalWrite(numeroPin, LOW);
}




void loop() {


 sonar(4, C4, 1000);
 sonar(5, D4, 1000);
 sonar(6, F4, 167);
 sonar(7, E4, 167);
 sonar(5, D4, 167);
 sonar(8, C5, 1000);
 sonar(9, G4, 500);




}
```

I tried it and it fails to compile.

Comment: Please provide the exact error the compiler is giving you. I suspect it is because you are not declaring the types of the parameters to `sonar()`.

Comment: You seem to need a basic C++ introduction tutorial. Or [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the basics of C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do in fact. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare parameters type in your function :
void sonar(int numeroPin, int sonido, int mydelay)
and avoid 'delay' as variable name as it is system reserved.

```
void setup() {

  for (int i = 2 ; i <= 9; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}

int C4 = 262; // LED 4
int D4 = 294; // LED 5
int E4 = 330; // LED 6
int F4 = 349; // LED 7
int G4 = 392; // LED 8
int C5 = 523; // LED 9

void sonar(int numeroPin, int sonido, int mydelay) {
  tone(2, sonido);
  digitalWrite(numeroPin, HIGH);
  delay(mydelay);
  digitalWrite(numeroPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  sonar(4, C4, 1000);
  sonar(5, D4, 1000);
  sonar(6, F4, 167);
  sonar(7, E4, 167);
  sonar(5, D4, 167);
  sonar(8, C5, 1000);
  sonar(9, G4, 500);
}
```